# Filtering Outliers in a Signal

Tags: filter, signal-processing, data-processing

### Input Data

I have an array of values of a signal over time, but it consists of many outliers and 0 values.

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1085, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 303, 301, 303, 301, 301, 301, 301, 301, 0, 0, 300, 300, 300, 298, 298, 298, 296, 300, 300, 301, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 256, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 236, 238, 0, 234, 0, 0, 0, 228, 0, 0, 1078, 0, 0, 0, 1078, 1076, 1078, 1076, 1076, 1076, 1074, 1074, 1072, 1072, 1074, 1074, 1074, 1074, 1076, 1076, 1074, 1074, 1074, 1072, 1074, 1074, 1074, 1074, 1074, 1074, 1074, 1074, 1074, 1074, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1886, 1880, 1880, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1074, 1074, 1074, 1076, 1076, 1076, 1074, 1074, 1074, 1072, 1072, 1074, 1076, 1076, 1076, 1076, 1074, 1074, 1074, 1078, 1074, 1066, 1061, 1061, 1057, 1053, 1059, 1046, 0, 1042, 1035, 1033, 1029, 1027, 1021, 1018, 1014, 1008, 1005, 1003, 993, 990, 673, 673, 673, 673, 673, 956, 950, 946, 935, 931, 924, 920, 911, 903, 896, 890, 885, 879, 871, 864, 853, 847, 841, 832, 823, 963, 808, 802, 787, 967, 969, 759, 748, 735, 725, 710, 697, 682, 667, 652, 635, 622, 603, 583, 560, 540, 517, 493, 468, 438, 412, 380, 0, 450, 500, 549, 592, 628, 661, 690, 720, 742, 1096, 150, 800, 819, 832, 845, 862, 1181, 885, 892, 901, 909, 920, 930, 935, 941, 1190, 1188, 1186, 967, 975, 978, 1173, 1173, 991, 997, 1003, 1005, 1006, 1008, 1012, 1014, 1020, 1021, 1021, 1023, 1029, 1031, 1031, 1033, 1035, 1038, 1040, 1044, 1044, 1042, 1048, 1048, 1048, 1053, 1053, 1053, 1053, 1053, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1080, 0, 0, 0, 1074, 1074, 1076, 1074, 1074, 1070, 1076, 1078, 1078, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1083, 0, 0, 0, 1072, 1070, 1066, 1065, 1065, 1063, 1061, 1053, 0, 0, 1040, 1273, 1035, 1275, 1031, 1027, 1020, 1018, 1012, 1008, 999, 995, 991, 986, 982, 978, 971, 965, 961, 958, 1121, 1117, 935, 423, 446, 915, 903, 900, 894, 892, 873, 866, 858, 853, 845, 1447, 826, 811, 804, 729, 20, 18, 757, 828, 738, 806, 712, 701, 24, 678, 945, 654, 643, 633, 622, 609, 1081, 1091, 1108, 1125, 536, 1155, 1183, 1215, 1224, 1239, 1254, 420, 399, 378, 0, 0, 0, 515, 553, 585, 616, 645, 669, 693, 710, 0, 0, 774, 789, 804, 815, 826, 845, 853, 866, 873, 1065, 894, 901, 905, 916, 924, 933, 939, 950, 952, 960, 960, 965, 973, 978, 982, 986, 991, 999, 1005, 1008, 1010, 1012, 1014, 1020, 1025, 1027, 1031, 836, 836, 836, 1042, 1040, 796, 1046, 1040, 753, 1040, 0, 0, 0, 1061, 0, 0, 1897, 1886, 1873, 1863, 1850, 0, 1828, 0, 1811, 1074, 1788, 1076, 0, 0, 1749, 1081, 1085, 1087, 1083, 1081, 1083, 1083, 0, 0, 1070, 1078, 1070, 1070, 1072, 1072, 1070, 1070, 1070, 1070, 0, 0, 1078, 1078, 1076, 1076, 1074, 1076, 0, 0, 1089, 1087, 1087, 1083, 1083, 1085, 1083, 1068, 1059, 0, 1053, 1055, 1053, 1048, 1837, 1320, 1044, 1316, 1312, 1036, 1051, 1027, 1025, 1044, 1291, 1282, 1042, 1018, 1036, 1035, 1005, 1228, 1029, 1027, 1190, 999, 1023, 1020, 1020, 1016, 1012, 1012, 1010, 1012, 1005, 997, 995, 993, 990, 986, 984, 980, 971, 1121, 969, 963, 960, 954, 950, 945, 1100, 939, 933, 926, 1121, 931, 946, 958, 969, 978, 986, 997, 1005, 1012, 1016, 1025, 1029, 1036, 1042, 1046, 1053, 1055, 1063, 1066, 1068, 1072, 1076, 1076, 1080, 1081, 1087, 1091, 1091, 1096, 1096, 1096, 1100, 1104, 1618, 1108, 1597, 1591, 1582, 1115, 1434, 1441, 1451, 1550, 1543, 1477, 1125, 1524, 1126, 1128, 1128, 1128, 1128, 1132, 1132, 1132, 1134, 1134, 1136, 1136, 1138, 1138, 1140, 1141, 1143, 1141, 1143, 1143, 1145, 1143, 1145, 1145, 1147, 1147, 1147, 1149, 1149, 1151, 1151, 1151, 1151, 1151, 1151, 1153, 1151, 1151, 1155, 1155, 1156, 1155, 1156, 1156, 1158, 1158, 1158, 1156, 1158, 1158, 1158, 1158, 1158, 1156, 1156, 1158, 1158, 1156, 1158, 1158, 1156, 1363, 1361, 1361, 1359, 1158, 1156, 1156, 1158, 1158, 1158, 1158, 1158, 1156, 1158, 1156, 1158, 1158, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1160, 1160, 1158, 1158, 1158, 1158, 1158, 1158, 1156, 1156, 1158, 1158, 1158, 1158, 1156, 1156, 1155, 1156, 1151, 1151, 1149, 1149, 1145, 1143, 1143, 1140, 1128, 1128, 1125, 1119, 0, 0, 1111, 1113, 1111, 1108, 1104, 1102, 1102, 1100, 1091, 1087, 1085, 1081, 1078, 1074, 1070, 1063, 1059, 1057, 1046, 1042, 1036, 1031, 1025, 1018, 1010, 1005, 997, 995, 984, 978, 969, 958, 948, 945, 931, 924, 915, 905, 894, 881, 871, 860, 851, 841, 830, 825, 0, 0, 885, 885, 888, 1089, 890, 886, 885, 712, 701, 684, 0, 0, 652, 673, 699, 913, 965, 1008, 1021, 1006, 813, 828, 840, 1057, 860, 1065, 1074, 886, 894, 898, 911, 915, 920, 1087, 931, 1087, 939, 948, 948, 956, 963, 965, 969, 971, 973, 976, 980, 982, 984, 986, 991, 993, 993, 997, 997, 1001, 1005, 1006, 1006, 1029, 1010, 1014, 1012, 1014, 1014, 1016, 1018, 1016, 1018, 1018, 1065, 1065, 1063, 1063, 1063, 1059, 1059, 1059, 1059, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1053, 0, 1046, 1046, 1050, 1048, 1048, 1057, 1061, 1065, 1070, 1072, 1074, 1078, 1081, 1083, 1087, 1091, 1093, 1095, 1102, 1104, 1111, 1111, 1113, 1119, 1125, 1128, 1130, 1134, 1141, 1147, 1153, 1156, 1276, 1170, 1175, 1183, 1188, 1192, 1201, 1303, 1303, 1220, 1231, 1239, 1248, 1256, 1303, 1275, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1391, 0, 1413, 1408, 0, 0, 1520, 1501, 0, 1398, 1576, 1421, 1438, 1447, 1460, 1471, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1552, 1565, 1588, 1610, 1627, 1650, 0, 1651, 0, 1888, 1554, 0, 1458, 1438, 1413, 1404, 1385, 1372, 1363, 1348, 1335, 1323, 1314, 1305, 1297, 1291, 1280, 1275, 1271, 1258, 1256, 1250, 1243, 1239, 1233, 1230, 1222, 1218, 1216, 1215, 1211, 1205, 1201, 1200, 1196, 1192, 1185, 1183, 1181, 1179, 1175, 1175, 1170, 1170, 1170, 1166, 1158, 1158, 1155, 1155, 1151, 1151, 1149, 1147, 1147, 1143, 1138, 1138, 1138, 1134, 1136, 1136, 1130, 1130, 0, 1128, 1128, 1128, 1128, 1128, 1125, 1125, 1125, 1123, 1121, 1121, 1117, 1119, 1117, 1117, 1117, 1113, 1115, 1115, 1115, 1113, 1093, 1091, 1087, 1085, 1083, 1080, 1087, 1059, 1053, 1053, 1042, 1038, 1029, 1025, 1021, 1014, 1008, 1001, 993, 990, 976, 973, 965, 958, 941, 939, 931, 922, 913, 909, 896, 881, 873, 866, 855, 843, 834, 826, 0, 796, 778, 770, 751, 738, 729, 718, 706, 697, 686, 675, 661, 646, 635, 620, 607, 592, 579, 562, 547, 532, 513, 495, 478, 457, 442, 420, 401, 378, 354, 333, 307, 285, 258, 232, 202, 174, 144, 112, 80, 45, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1083, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 607, 611, 609, 616, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

[image: raw signal]

### Goal

The goal is to obtain the main underlying signal, as drawn here: [image: goal]

As a first improvement to extract the main signal, I replaced each 0 with the trend of data by calculating the slope between the intermediate non-zero points, and interpolating the values: [image: first improvement]

### But, how can I remove outliers?

I have tried the following:

1. Same approach as replacing each 0 value, but then checking when the difference between the last point is > 100. This approach does not work when there are multiple consecutive outliers, as can be seen in the interval of [450-480]
2. Moving average filter: it does not get rid of outliers, only reduces them. The points that are not outliers but part of the main signal also get affected too much, even after testing different window sizes.
3. For each data point, checking when it deviates too much from the standard deviation and variance of the entire signal. However, as the current trend of a certain interval is quite different over time, this approach does not work.

I would preferably not hard code any values used for eliminating outliers, as other signals may not be within the same scale as this one. I used Python, but a solution in another language is also welcome. Thanks for helping me!

Comment: seems you tried some good stuff, I have a feeling you'll get better luck asking somewhere else because this is just a signal processing problem, has nothing to do with code.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying fourier transform, try and see how this signal looks in the frequency domain, if there is any frequency which you can remove and transform back and see if the signal holds. This works if the outliers are of a different frequency than the signal (look up noise reduction).

I thought at first you could just discard the outliers by checking the difference with the "real" signal, but it's hard to tell what's the real signal, especially compared to your example (the signal itself has some big jumps). If you have some kind of model for the signal, perhaps you can sort of weigh whether a point is likely to be part of the signal or not (for example if it's a sinusoid).

If you discard the first part of the signal though, capturing the other part might be possible by forcing the signal to be continuative (what's that called again), that is not allow the signal to have any jumps (what is a jump? well you'll have to compare it to the slope of the points before and it can't be X more than that). It would not be perfect though, for example I assume it would go all the way down at the 200 mark. This could maybe be compensated by removing the zeros in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using an approximate optimization algorithm based on dynamic programming. The optimization problem would be to find k samples in the signal where it copies the previous value, with the objective of minimizing the sum of absolute value differences between adjacent samples of the processed signal. Higher values of k lead to heavier smoothing, and using other norms (e.g. squared differences) leads to heavier penalization of individual outliers.

Suppose the signal is n values, and k is called the number of points - the number of samples it can skip. You start with two n*k arrays opt and last, where opt[i, j] is the minimum achievable sum of squared differences up to the ith sample of the signal, with j points remaining; and last[i, j] is the last non-skipped sample point. last[0, j] = 0 for all j.

Then an approximate optimum opt[i, j] is the minimum of two possibilities:

- Either spending a point to duplicate the last sample: opt[i, j] = opt[i-1, j+1], and last[i, j] = last[i-1, j+1].
- Or not: opt[i, j] = opt[i-1, j] + |x[i] - x[last[i-1, j]|, last[i, j] = i.

If j = k, it's not possible to spend any points (since all points are still intact), thus the first option is not allowed. It's not possible to spend a point at the first sample either, because you can't duplicate sample -1.

I think the optimum is approximate because the two branches could have the same value, yet have different last points, and future decisions could depend on what the last value is. You could get an exact optimum by parameterizing over last as well, but that would give a 3D array and I imagine it would become impractical very quickly.

The approximate optimum for the whole signal is the minimal element of the opt[n] row, and tracing back through the last array should let you find out where the points were spent.

You could also do a greedy version:

1. For every sample x[i] but the first, insert the tuple (|x[i]-x[i-1]|, i) into a max-first priority queue.
2. Pop the highest value off the priority queue. Say the index is j.
3. Remove the tuple (|x[j+1]-x[j]|, j+1) from the priority queue, as the distance will soon change.
4. Copy x[j-1] to x[j], overwriting the jth sample with the value of the j-1th.
5. Insert the tuple (|x[j+1]-x[j]|, j+1), i.e. the new distance for sample j+1, back into the priority queue.
6. Repeat from 2 until the number of distinct samples modified equals k.